# Lighthouse CI - Unable to set Authentication for Terraform K8s Deployment

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, lighthouse, lighthouse-ci

I'm trying to set `Lighthouse CI` Authentication using `Terraform` `K8s` Deployment(https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/main/docs/server.md#basic-authentication) but I keep getting a `403` Error. I have tried below steps but I get the same message.

FYI, the `password` is set from `kubectl_manifest` `resourece`

1. Using Terraform Set `ENV` from `kubernetes_deployment` `resource`

```
env {
    name = "LHCI_BASIC_AUTH__USERNAME"
    value = "username"
}

env {
    name = "LHCI_BASIC_AUTH__PASSWORD"
    value_from {
      secret_key_ref {
        name = "password"
        key  = "password"
      }
    }
}
```

2. Different approach for using Terraform Set `ENV` from `kubernetes_deployment` resource(https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/security.html#enable-authentication-on-atlantis-web-server)

```
env {
    name = "ATLANTIS_WEB_BASIC_AUTH"
    value = "true"
}

env {
    name = "ATLANTIS_WEB_USERNAME"
    value = "user"
}

env {
    name = "LHCI_BASIC_AUTH__PASSWORD"
    value_from {
      secret_key_ref {
        name = "password"
        key  = "password"
      }
    }
}
```

3. Using `Helm` `Chart` with Terraform `helm_release` resource - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cowboysysop/lighthouse-ci

   After looking at the source code - https://github.com/cowboysysop/charts/blob/a12e738a57977c7c6e84cb219ae6967fddae266e/charts/lighthouse-ci/values.yaml#L201 - `env` `var` names used in this example `3.1` look incorrect.

- 3.1 Set ENV

```
resource "helm_release" "lhci" {
  name  = "lhci"
  chart = "lighthouse-ci"
  repository = "https://cowboysysop.github.io/charts/"
  namespace  = "lhci"

  set {
    name  = "basicAuth.username"
    value = "user"
  }

  set {
    name  = "basicAuth.password"
    value = "password"
  }
}
```

- 3.2 Set ENV (using different ENV naming convention)

```
resource "helm_release" "lhci" {
  name  = "lhci"
  chart = "lighthouse-ci"
  repository = "https://cowboysysop.github.io/charts/"
  namespace  = "lhci"

  set {
    name  = "basicAuthUsername"
    value = "user"
  }

  set {
    name  = "basicAuthPassword"
    value = "password"
  }
}
```

The above steps have been resulting in the same error. What is the proper way to enable authentication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be specific to my case but I went with the first approach and changed the `http_get` path for `readiness_probe` from `/` to `/healthz`. The issue got fixed.

e.g.

```
readiness_probe {
  http_get {
    path = "/healthz"
    port = "9001"
  }
}
```